# Release APK size

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, apk

I'm working on a BLE android project. The app's functionality is to receive data from nRF52833 through Bluetooth and save it as a file in local directory. I downloaded Nordic Semiconductor's android nRF toolbox open source code and made changes in that to work as we needed.

Here is the Github repo of nRF toolbox https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Toolbox

nRF toolbox has so many functionalities for BLE. Only one part is we needed. So I removed all the unwanted files. It's working fine. But the issue is apk size. Debug apk size is nearly 36MB. But their release apk size is like 3MB to 4MB.

Play Store app link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox&hl=en_IN&gl=US

So my question is if I build release apk means, my app size will also become that much smaller or I need to use some compression technique And one more question, nrf toolbox can run on android 10 and our app can run only up to android pie. Is there any reason for an app to not run on android 10?

**Note**: AndroidX is enabled for the project.

Since it's a company project, I can't share my code.

Comment: _"if I build release apk means, my app size will also become that much smaller?"_ Try it and see what happens. _"Is there any reason for an app to not run on android 10?"_ It's not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: nrf toolbox can run on android 10, but our app can't. Is there anything I have to do extra to make that app run on android 10?

Answer (score 0):

you probably have Proguard enabled for your release build - it takes some time, so its disabled when debug for faster building APK purposes. some [DOC](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

and why your app isn't working on Android 10? without a single line of code or exception its impossible to guess. maybe check out [behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all) in Android 10, maybe you will find component, which you are using and its behavior changed. `nRF` lib should work fine on 10, so the problem is in your code

Answer (score 0):

you should add this to your app gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

`minifyEnabled` will allow `obfuscation` of your app and is a must for `shrinkResources`.
to set up your obfuscation you will need to update your `proguard-rules.pro` files with the rules for each dependency you have in your gradle file, and make sure that your `Models` used for network calls are with the `@Keep` annotation